# Compilador de Angular compila módulos que no están siendo utilizados

Tags: angular

Recién instalé una librería de componentes para angular llamada 'PrimeNG', aún no la estoy implementando en mi aplicación, pero el compilador de angular ya la está añadiendo al proceso de compilación (Está compilando toda la librería).

```
ng build --prod
Compiling primeng/overlaypanel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/panel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/panelmenu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/password : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/picklist : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/progressspinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/radiobutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/rating : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/scrollpanel : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/selectbutton : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/sidebar : es2015 as esm2015
```

Yo solo pretendo usar un par de componentes de esta librería (quiero que angular solo compile los módulos que voy a usar).

¿Alguíen sabe como funciona este proceso y como puedo solucionarlo? de antemano gracias.

Comment: Importaste todas las librerias?

Comment: No, de hecho no he importado ninguna. Solo instalé la librería, aún no la estoy usando en mi proyecto pero el compilador de angular ya está compilando la librería.